# Build falied while running iOS Code from Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am taking my iPhone app code from SVN and then trying to build it via Jenkins.  Xcode version 7.3.1

But I am getting the following error -

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Ld build/Release-iphoneos/xxxxxxx.app/xxxxxxx normal armv7
(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have already spent days to resolve this and would appreciate if some one can help me. Let me know if more details are needed.
Thanks.

Comment: That's not enough information; more detail is available from the build.

Comment: What commands you used to generate the build? or you have used the plugin from jenkins? which xcode version you are using? Are you using the pod in your code?

Comment: I am using jenkins via plugin. Plugin name - Xcode integration, Version - 1.4.9.  Xcode version - 7.3.1. Yes I am using pods in my code.